# How to create a base case for a tuple in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, tuples

I have the following function:

```
encode_single :: (Eq a) => [a] -> (Int, a)
encode_single (x:xs) = (count xs + 1, x)
```

However, Haskell complained about needing a base case, but I don't know how to do this because of the generic `a` type.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the intention of `encode_single` ? What is it supposed to do? What is `count` function?

Comment: It's the 10th problem from: https://wiki.haskell.org/99_questions/1_to_10, count is just a custom function for finding the length of a list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, what you received is only a *warning*, not an error. Haskell does not **need** the base case of the empty list, it just *suggests* it.

Partial functions are most often an anti-pattern in functional programming so it just points out something that **may** be wrong. You can avoid the warning in different ways.

The first one is to make your function safe: if it cannot always return a value it's return type shouldn't be `(Int, a)` but `Maybe (Int, a)`, so you could do:

```
encode_single :: (Eq a) => [a] -> Maybe (Int, a)
encode_single [] = Nothing
encode_single (x:xs) = Just (count xs + 1, x)
```

Otherwise you'd *have* to return a meaningful value for the empty case (just returning `undefined` isn't better than not defining that case). It *might* be appropriate to do somethign like:

```
encode_single [] = (0, undefined)
```

However this assumes that any code that uses the result of `encode_single` will not evaluate the second element of the tuple if the first element is zero (note that if the list isn't empty the first element is always positive, so `0` can be used as a sentinel value).

This may or may not be the case. However one thing is sure: this is not compile-time safe so you may receive some run-time errors when calling such a function.

Answer (score 2):

Simply enough: at the type you desire you cannot write a total function of that specification. You need to change the type.

You can either add a default `a` or indicate partiality using `Maybe`.

```
encode_single :: a -> [a] -> (Int, a)
encode_single :: [a] -> Maybe (Int, a)
```

Comment: s/of that specification/in any way at all/

Answer (score 0):

if you cannot change the type signature, you can piggyback on `head` i.e.

```
encode_single :: [a] -> (Int, a)
encode_single a = (length a, head a)
```

obviously, empty list input is not handled properly.